# How to add kAudioUnitSubType_LowPassFilter in a AUGraph?

Tags: ios, core-audio, augraph

I am trying to add `kAudioUnitSubType_LowPassFilter` to an `AUGraph` but do not succeed in that.

I implemented the following code:

```
// create a new AUGraph
[Utilities checkError:NewAUGraph(&self.info->mGraph)
            operation: "Couldn't create a new AUGraph"];

AUNode rioNode;
AUNode lpfNode;

// Create filter audio unit
AudioComponentDescription lpfAU_description;
lpfAU_description.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Effect;
lpfAU_description.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_LowPassFilter;
lpfAU_description.componentFlags = 0;
lpfAU_description.componentFlagsMask = 0;
lpfAU_description.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;


// Create RemoteIO audio unit
AudioComponentDescription rioAU_description;
rioAU_description.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
rioAU_description.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
rioAU_description.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
rioAU_description.componentFlags = 0;
rioAU_description.componentFlagsMask = 0;

[Utilities checkError:AUGraphAddNode(self.info->mGraph, &rioAU_description, &rioNode)
            operation: "Couldn't add Graph Node"];
[Utilities checkError:AUGraphAddNode(self.info->mGraph, &lpfAU_description, &lpfNode )
            operation: "Couldn't add Graph Node"];

// Open graph
[Utilities checkError:AUGraphOpen(self.info->mGraph)
            operation: "Couldn't open graph"];

// Get audio units
[Utilities checkError:AUGraphNodeInfo(self.info->mGraph, lpfNode, NULL, &self.info->lpfUnit)
            operation: "Couldn't link node to audio unit"];

[Utilities checkError:AUGraphNodeInfo(self.info->mGraph, rioNode, NULL, &self.info->rioUnit)
            operation: "Couldn't link node to audio unit"];

// Make connections
[Utilities checkError:AUGraphConnectNodeInput(self.info->mGraph, rioNode, 1, lpfNode, 1)
            operation: "Couldn't connect remoteIO output scope bus 1 to filter input scope bus 1"];// input -> filter

[Utilities checkError: AUGraphConnectNodeInput(self.info->mGraph, lpfNode, 0, rioNode, 0)
            operation: "Couldn't connect filter output scope bus 0 to remoteIO input scope bus 0"]; // filter -> output

// Enable IO for input and output (recording and playing)
AudioUnitElement kRemoteIOInputScopeMic = 1;
AudioUnitElement kRemoteIOOutputScopeSpeaker = 0;

UInt32 enableInput = 1;
[Utilities checkError:AudioUnitSetProperty (self.info->rioUnit,
                                            kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO,
                                            kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                            kRemoteIOInputScopeMic,
                                            &enableInput,
                                            sizeof(enableInput))
            operation: "Couldn't enable RIO input"];

// set up the rio unit for playback
UInt32 enableOutput = 1;
[Utilities checkError:AudioUnitSetProperty (self.info->rioUnit,
                                            kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO,
                                            kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                                            kRemoteIOOutputScopeSpeaker,
                                            &enableOutput,
                                            sizeof(enableOutput))
            operation: "Couldn't enable RIO output"];

// Set property to low-pass filter
AudioUnitSetParameter(self.info->lpfUnit,
                      kLowPassParam_CutoffFrequency,
                      kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                      0,
                      1000,
                      0);



// Set callbacks
// Callback for input
AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
callbackStruct.inputProc = recordingCallback;
callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void*) self;


[Utilities checkError: AudioUnitSetProperty(self.info->rioUnit,
                                            kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback,
                                            kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                                            1, // Input bus
                                            &callbackStruct,
                                            sizeof(AURenderCallbackStruct))
            operation: "AudioUnitSetProperty set RenderCalback"];

// Callback to render data
callbackStruct.inputProc = renderCallback;
callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void*) self;


[Utilities checkError: AudioUnitSetProperty(self.info->rioUnit,
                                            kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
                                            kAudioUnitScope_Input, //kAudioUnitScope_Global, ????
                                            0, // Output bus
                                            &callbackStruct,
                                            sizeof(AURenderCallbackStruct))
            operation: "AudioUnitSetProperty set RenderCalback"];

[Utilities checkError: AUGraphInitialize(self.info->mGraph)
            operation: "Couldn't initialize graph"];


// Input ASBD
AudioStreamBasicDescription inputasbd;
UInt32 propSize = sizeof(inputasbd);
[Utilities checkError:AudioUnitGetProperty(self.info->rioUnit,
                                           kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                                           kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                           1,
                                           &inputasbd,
                                           &propSize)
            operation:"Failed to get stream format of microphone input scope"];

// Output ASBD
AudioStreamBasicDescription outputasbd;
UInt32 typeByteSize   = sizeof(float);
outputasbd.mBitsPerChannel   = 8 * typeByteSize;
outputasbd.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
outputasbd.mBytesPerFrame    = typeByteSize * outputasbd.mChannelsPerFrame;
outputasbd.mFormatFlags      = kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat | kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved;
outputasbd.mFormatID         = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
outputasbd.mFramesPerPacket  = 1;
outputasbd.mBytesPerPacket   = outputasbd.mFramesPerPacket * outputasbd.mBytesPerFrame;
outputasbd.mSampleRate       = inputasbd.mSampleRate;

// Set stream format to output scope of input bus
[Utilities checkError:AudioUnitSetProperty (self.info->rioUnit,
                                            kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                                            kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                                            1,
                                            &inputasbd,
                                            sizeof (AudioStreamBasicDescription))
            operation: "Couldn't set ASBD for RIO on output scope / bus 1"];

// Set format on inputscope of output bus
[Utilities checkError:AudioUnitSetProperty(self.info->rioUnit,
                                           kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                                           kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                           0,
                                           &outputasbd,
                                           sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription))
            operation: "Couldn't set ASBD for RIO on input scope / bus 0"];


// Start AUGraph
[Utilities checkError:AUGraphStart(self.info->mGraph)
        operation: "Couldn't start AUGraph"];
```

But unfortunately the AU Graph couldn't start with this code (OSStatus -10863).
When I remove the filter by commenting out the `AUGraphConnectNodeInput` methods or use the remoteIO AU directly audio is played from the mic to speaker without problems.

Could anybody give me a hint what I do wrong with configuring `kAudioUnitSubType_LowPassFilter`?

Comment: What's your concept about "having done something wrong with configuring" `kAudioUnitSubType_LowPassFilter`? What makes you sure about it? Have you tried connecting a unit of another subtype?

Comment: In fact I meant that I do not really know where the problem is located. I also tried to put a `kAudioUnitSubType_MultiChannelMixer` to the graph (with only one input from the mic), but I receive the same error code.

Comment: `OSStatus -10863 = kAudioToolboxErr_CannotDoInCurrentContext`. The problem may be in your render callback which seems to put the `remoteIO` AU into play-through configuration. Try commenting it out when you make the `AUGraphConnectNodeInput()` connections and see if anything will happen?

Comment: My current app uses the remote AU directly but it works without problems with the implementations of the callbacks. Since I also use a FIR filter in the render callback, I just wanted to change that for an AU to improve performance. Therefore, I would not expect problems with the callbacks or stream formats (commenting out did not change the error code).  I appreciate other thoughts.

Comment: It is expected that your code should work well in a single AU configuration. The problem seems to happen when you add another AU into the DSP chain and make it a _graph_. There have been a few posts on SO about problems when using `kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback` mechanism for registering a callback within a -graph_. Try registering your callback in the following way: `AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback (self.info->mGraph, lpfNode, busNumber,  &callbackStruct)` - take a look at the reference pages and code examples.

Comment: As mentioned below I was able to get the filter working. However, I still have problems with the callbacks. As you suggested I tried to register these on the graph but I was only able to get the render callback working (the input callback does not work). For this problem I asked a new question on SO [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924273/configuring-input-and-render-callbacks-in-a-augraph-configuration). Possibly, you might be able to help me out here as well! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT 2:

Change your ASBD to stereo.  The filter requires it.

I think `AUGraphConnectNodeInput(self.info->mGraph, rioNode, 1, lpfNode, 1)` is supposed to be `AUGraphConnectNodeInput(self.info->mGraph, rioNode, 1, lpfNode, 0)`.  The inDestInputNumber argument is essentially the input bus, and the filters just have one bus, so that argument should be bus 0;  If that doesn't fix things, post what's going on in your `setStreamFormatWithInputASBD` method (if relevant).  Either way, I usually will set all of my output ASBDs explicitly to match the input of the unit it is connected to.

Given a graph like this inUnit->unitA->unitB->outUnit set ASBDs using this pattern:

(pseudo code for audioUnitGetProperty and setproperty for ASBD)

```
unitB.outputASBD = outUnit.inputASBD; 
unitA.outputASBD = unitB.inputASBD; 
inUnit.outputASBD = unitA.inputASBD;
```

Sometimes this isn't necessary, but sometimes it is!  Most of the filters take a mandatory stereo float ASBD as input.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't work in iOS, but I'm familiar with the OSX CoreAudio API. RemoteIO AU is iOS specific, and its API is similar to the HAL AU on the mac, @Dave. The render callback is responsible for play-through configuration, defining connection between input and output busses, while input callback might perhaps be extraneous. However, if you connect another AU between the input busses of the RemoteIO AU, it's likely that a render callback registered in such a way serves no purpose. There are other mechanisms of registering callbacks in AUGraph which don't break the API.

Comment: Further on, you are _not exact_ about `inSoruceInputNumber ` and `inDestInputNumber`  being "essentially the input channel, and the filters just have one channel", @Dave. These are _the bus numbers of
the nodes_ and should not be confused with the number of _audio_ channels per frame in the stream format. (-:

Comment: Although I also tried to change the bus numbers it did not change the error code. Regarding the comment of user3078414 I assume that these were correct. Further, I edited my question with the ASBD’s I used for clarity. In my input callback I perform several analyses (including FIR filtering), put audio on a circular buffer and recording could be performed. I use the render callback to render audio from the buffer and to play and plot the audio.

Comment: And edited answer with solution, you need to use a stereo ASBD.

Comment: Finally, I got it working! The problem was indeed related to the asbd's used, especially the weird requirement of 32bit float 2 channel for the filter. But also due to the fact that units with a callback should not be connected in the graph! Unfortunately, I still have a problem with configuring both my existing input and render callbacks on the I/O remote AU (for that problem I will ask another question on SO).